# NextJs Image unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm building an infinite slider loop in which all images are pegged to each other in a row and move together from left to right covering the full width of the screen at all times. When using the regular `<img>` tag everything looks fine. However, when I try to replace `<img>` with Next's Image component things get messed up including the speed of the animation, the aspect ratio of the individual images and what's worse the moving images don't cover the full width of the screen anymore.

Here's the `<img>` code that works and the tailwindcss animation:

```
 <div className="flex top-0 animate-marquee2 w-36">
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/2.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/5.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/1.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/7.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/3.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/8.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/0.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/4.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/9.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/5.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/10.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/7.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/6.png" />
        <img className="slideImage" src="/slider/1.png" />
      </div>
```

> 

```
module.exports = {
      mode: "jit",
      important: true,
      content: [
        "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
      ],
      theme: {
      
          animation: {
            marquee: 'marquee 20s linear infinite',
            marquee2: 'marquee2 15s linear infinite'
         
          },
          keyframes: {
            marquee: {
              '0%': { transform: 'translateX(0%)' },
              '100%': { transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }
            },
            marquee2: {
              '0%': { transform: 'translateX(-100%)' },
              '100%': { transform: 'translateX(0%)' }
            }
          }
        },
      },
```

What I tried to do then is replacing `<img>` with Next/Image but the behavior is completely different as explained before. Any suggestions why that is?

```
import Image from "next/image";

import Img0 from "/public/slider/0.png";
import Img1 from "/public/slider/1.png";
import Img2 from "/public/slider/2.png";
import Img3 from "/public/slider/3.png";
import Img4 from "/public/slider/4.png";
import Img5 from "/public/slider/5.png";
import Img6 from "/public/slider/6.png";
import Img7 from "/public/slider/7.png";
import Img8 from "/public/slider/8.png";
import Img9 from "/public/slider/9.png";
import Img10 from "/public/slider/10.png";

function Slider() {


  return (
    <div className="whitespace-nowrap overflow-hidden pt-6">
      <div className="flex animate-marquee">
        <div className="flex relative outline-none w-36 h-36">
          <Image
            src={Img0}
            alt="random image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex relative outline-none w-36 h-36">
          <Image
            src={Img1}
            alt="random image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex relative outline-none w-36 h-36">
          <Image
            src={Img2}
            alt="random image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex relative outline-none w-36 h-36">
          <Image
            src={Img3}
            alt="random image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex relative outline-none w-36 h-36">
          <Image
            src={Img4}
            alt="random image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex relative outline-none w-36 h-36">
          <Image
            src={Img5}
            alt="random image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex relative outline-none w-36 h-36">
          <Image
            src={Img6}
            alt="random image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex relative outline-none w-36 h-36">
          <Image
            src={Img7}
            alt="random image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex relative outline-none w-36 h-36">
          <Image
            src={Img8}
            alt="random image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex relative outline-none w-36 h-36">
          <Image
            src={Img9}
            alt="random image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex relative outline-none w-36 h-36">
          <Image
            src={Img10}
            alt="random image"
            layout="fill"
            objectFit="cover"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default Slider;
```

Comment: Are you aware that next `<Image>` tags implement lazy-loading features?  My guess is that your app hasn't loaded the images yet so it can't loop.  This sounds like a unique use case for images and maybe using the next's Image tag isn't the best fit.  Having said that, I might try changing the `priority` to `true` see if it preloads the images.

Comment: Can you create a code snippet ?